# Merge two queries and order them on base of created_at in Laravel

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, model

I've created Models for two tables. Now I want to perform a query and merge the results based on `created_at`.

My queries are:

```
    $first  =  RequestF::where('userId','=',$userId)->get();
    $second =  RequestS::where('userId','=',$userId)->get();
```

I can merge them using:

```
     foreach($first as $f) {
        $second->add($f);
     }
```

But this simply adds `$first`-objects at the end of `$second` and I cannot get them by order based on `created_at`.

How can I merge this two queries and order them at the same time?
Thank you.

**Update** 
After @MargusPala suggestion, this is my result after `$second->toArray()`, but it's weird that one object is not in order!! object number 10:

```
{
  "status" : "Success",
  "data" : {
"showcases" : {
  "10" : {
    "userName" : "mojtaba_talebii",
    "created_at" : "2015-04-22 10:51:25",
    "type" : "F"
  },
  "2" : {
    "userName" : "mojtaba_talebii",
    "created_at" : "2015-04-23 10:14:32",
    "type" : "L"
  },
  "3" : {
    "userName" : "mojtaba_talebii",
    "created_at" : "2015-04-23 10:15:00",
    "type" : "L"
  },
  "11" : {
    "userName" : "mojtaba_talebii",
    "created_at" : "2015-04-27 09:54:56",
    "type" : "F"
  },
  "4" : {
    "userName" : "mojtaba_talebii",
    "created_at" : "2015-04-23 11:22:09",
    "type" : "L"
  },
  "5" : {
    "userName" : "mojtaba_talebii",
    "created_at" : "2015-04-26 10:42:38",
    "type" : "L"
  },
  "6" : {
    "userName" : "mojtaba_talebii",
    "created_at" : "2015-04-27 09:59:03",
    "type" : "L"
  },
  "7" : {
    "userName" : "mojtaba_talebii",
    "created_at" : "2015-04-27 09:59:23",
    "type" : "L"
  },
  "0" : {
    "userName" : "mojtaba_talebii",
    "created_at" : "2015-04-22 11:26:25",
    "type" : "L"
  },
  "8" : {
    "userName" : "mojtaba_talebii",
    "created_at" : "2015-04-27 10:05:19",
    "type" : "L"
  },
  "1" : {
    "userName" : "mojtaba_talebii",
    "created_at" : "2015-04-23 10:13:53",
    "type" : "L"
  },
  "9" : {
    "userName" : "mojtaba_talebii",
    "created_at" : "2015-04-27 10:05:33",
    "type" : "L"
  }
}
  },
 "message" : "Here is results"
}
```

That's weird, and other thing, how can I get result ass JSON Array, not JSON Object.

Comment: try this: $first  =  RequestF::where('userId','=',$userId)->orderBy("created_at", "ASC")->get();
    $second =  RequestS::where('userId','=',$userId)->orderby("created_at","ASC")->get();

Comment: @CoolD I know that, but after merging `$first` and `$second`, the objects of second query is added at the end of first query, and not ordered.

Answer (score 4):

Laravel has sortBy() function which allows you to sort collections. Use it like this

```
$second = $second->sortBy(function($s)
{
    return $s->created_at;
});
```

Comment: This is exactly what I wanted, but after trying to return response using `$second->toArray()`, it returns JSON Objects, instead of JSON Array. is there any solution for that?

Comment: You can use `dd($second->toArray())` so see what the Collection is converted into and how to fix it. Make sure you later do `return $second->toArray();`

Comment: Actually I find out, my result is not ordered, it's weird, but I updated question.